# Karma coverage istanbul does not create folder

Tags: karma-jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage

I am trying to integrate a code coverage reporter to my karma tests.

I set up the following changes in my config:

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],

  // base output directory. If you include %browser% in the path it will be replaced with the karma browser name
  dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),

  // if using webpack and pre-loaders, work around webpack breaking the source path
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
},

reporters: config.coverage ? ['kjhtml', 'dots', 'coverage-istanbul'] : ['kjhtml', 'dots'],
```

But unfortnetly, it does not create a `coverage` folder.

Here is my  [full karma.config.js](https://gist.github.com/AmitMY/5d84223ce2262bd2ba3a99275a78e9b6)

What am I doing wrong here? Note, that I am calling `karma start ./karma.conf.js --coverage` and even checked without the config coverage parameter.

Comment: Can you see the test results on chrome consoles?

Comment: @Xlee Yes, I can see the tests report in browser, but no coverage

Answer (score 2):

Given you have `text-summary` outputs on Chrome console and you already have the **base** directory for the reporter specified, you just need to explicitly tell the reporter which sub directory should be used for different report type:

Try to add this entry under `coverageIstanbulReporter` (from repo's README):

```
   // Most reporters accept additional config options. You can pass these through the `report-config` option
  'report-config': {

    // all options available at: https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbul-reports/blob/590e6b0089f67b723a1fdf57bc7ccc080ff189d7/lib/html/index.js#L135-L137
    html: {
      // outputs the report in ./coverage/html
      subdir: 'html'
    }

  }
```

Comment: Added, still the same - not creating `coverage/html`

Comment: Project root does not have `coverage/` folder?

Comment: Nope. I tried to create it manually and run again, but no `html` folder inside.

Comment: Try not to create manually and see whether karma generate the coverage/ folder first?

Comment: Removed it, ran karma with coverage, no folder

Comment: Interesting, there is no console/Terminal info to share?

Comment: Nothing interesting in the terminal. this is the browser - https://imgur.com/wAj7AKt

Comment: It's not coverage report. You need to open the dev tools console to see the text summary

Comment: oh misunderstood.. No, I don't see anything in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153907/discussion-between-xlee-and-amit).

Comment: Thanks. I actually just finished work, and got the karma coverage reporter to work (not Istanbul). I’ll close this with my now working reporter when I am back at work. Thanks again

Comment: Np, im using `karma-coverage` to generate report as well ;)